# Display both comments on dialogbox(Java)

Tags: java, swing, dialog, awt, joptionpane

[comment 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57aVX.png)
[comment 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAl37.png)

How do i make both comments display on the dialog box?

Below is my code for reference.

```
private class HandleTextField implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        String string  = "";

        if (e.getSource () == textFieldArray [0])
        {
            string = String.format("1. %s", e.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if (e.getSource () == textFieldArray [1])
        {
            string = String.format("2. %s", e.getActionCommand());
        }

        Object [] fields ={
            "Summary of my changes" , string
        };

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fields, "My sugestion to the course", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You need to design a better UI. It doesn't make sense that you need to use the Enter key when typing each comment. You will only ever have an event generated for one text field at a time. So you might need to add a "Display Comments" button. Then when the user clicks the button you get the text from both text fields and display the option pane.

Comment: Yes but thats what my professor wants for this assignment. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following untested code will put the contents of both TextFields in your dialog when either of them trigger an action.

```
private class HandleTextField implements ActionListener {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    StringBuilder string  = new StringBuilder();

    if (e.getSource () == textFieldArray[0] || 
        e.getSource () == textFieldArray[1]){
      string.append(String.format(
          "1. %s", textFieldArray[0].getText())
        );
      string.append(String.format(
          "2. %s", textFieldArray[1].getText())
        );
    }

    String[] fields = {"Summary of my changes" , string.toString()};

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fields, "My suggestion to the course", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it didn't work. I got a long string of text "javax.swing.JTextField(,64,285,224x20,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI......" instead of what i typed in my textfield.

Comment: I'm surprised it even compiled -- I've replaced the incorrect getActionCommand() with getText(), should help.

Comment: Yeah, i added e.getActionCommand() to your previous post. Anyway, i got it to work! Thanks so much your help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

So, if you observe, you are overlapping your string in every condition. If you want both appears, you should at least do this:

```
private class HandleTextField implements ActionListener {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
      String string  = "";

      if (e.getSource () == textFieldArray [0]){
         string += String.format("1. %s", e.getActionCommand());
      } 
      if (e.getSource () == textFieldArray [1]) {
         string += String.format("2. %s", e.getActionCommand());
      }

      String[] fields = {"Summary of my changes" , string};

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fields, "My sugestion to the course", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
   }
}
```

I would suggest to do this code like this (it is more recommended to append stuffs on your String object):

```
private class HandleTextField implements ActionListener {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
     StringBuilder string  = new StringBuilder();

     if (e.getSource () == textFieldArray [0]){
        string.append(String.format("1. %s", e.getActionCommand()));
     } 
     if (e.getSource () == textFieldArray [1]) {
        if(string != null && string.toString().length() > 0){
           string.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        string.append(String.format("2. %s", e.getActionCommand()));
     }

     String[] fields = {"Summary of my changes" , string.toString()};

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fields, "My sugestion to the course", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try that code? It looks as though the result will be exactly the same as the original code, as `string` is initialised for each event, and each event will have only one source.

Comment: Once I don't know which action it is set it is hard to foresaw the behavior.

I can suppose that "string" maybe could be extracted to other scope (not so internal) then it can handle both information, or even just have these fields and their previous states to compare them and trigger this listener in other component.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the code didn't work. It still have the same output as mine.